# HTML transfer to Filezilla (images won't show)

Tags: html

"This won't transfer to the FileZilla correctly from Notepad++ the images  won't show? I asked the teacher for help, but he doesn't know the material well enough to trouble shoot the problem. Internet Explorer will run the module and the text runs just fine, but Google Chrome say Error 2, and FileZilla won't register the pictures, they only show as black box icons, pls help"

```
<html>

<head>
    <img src="images/images12.jpg" style="padding:6px" align="center" height="400px" width="400px">
    <style>
        #this is the set up for the text body {
            font-family: Papyrus, fantsy;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: Papyrus, fantsy;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h2 {
            font-family: Papyrus, fantsy;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    header for the home page
    <title> Woody's Wondering's</title>
    <header>

        <h1>Which way did Woody Go?</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <b>
<a href="Home.html">Home    </a> &nbsp;
<a href="places.html">Places To Go    </a> &nbsp;
<a href="free.html">Whats Free    </a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="kids.html"> Kids....Cheap easy Fun!   </a>
<br>
<a href="Adults.html">Adults Only   </a>
</b>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h2>You Next Adventure is only a click away!!!</h2>

        <p>Welcome to Woody's Wonderings were everything is cheep and easy to find in Ohio.....How Cheap, well pracically 20 dollars to free. </p>

        <h2>Meeting all your fun fun needs!!!</h2>

        <p>Keeping the site updated with new and improved places & Events year around

        </p>

    </main>
    <footer>
        <small><i>
Jessica Harper</i></small>
    </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there!  Welcome to Stack Overflow, and congrats on asking your first question!  It is a bit unclear what you're asking.  Maybe consider breaking your question into different paragraphs that address 1. What you're trying to do. 2. What you've already tried doing to accomplish it 3. Very specifically, what your question is.  Best of luck solving your problem.  =)

Comment: Also, it's probably not my place to say and I realize it's not relevant to your question: but from a graphic design perspective Papyrus is usually strongly discouraged as a font choice.  I'd recommend checking out something like https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/12/what-font-should-i-use-five-principles-for-choosing-and-using-typefaces/

Comment: Thanks...I will...I had to drop the class HTML- my teacher was a total diva...and would not trouble shoot the issues I had with the graphics...he zero'd the project...but I plan to push on with the project without him or his class- Second time I have dropped the class, because the instructors they higher in my college to teach HTML aren't qualified at all- they just go by the book- Horrible experience- all together

Answer (score 0):

Your image is in the head of the html document. Correct structure for html is,

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The HTML5 Template</title>
    <!–– Style sheets & other importations go here ––>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!–– Your content goes here ––>

    <!–– Javascript files go here ––>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp),

> The  element is a container for metadata (data about data) and
>   is placed between the  tag and the  tag.
>
> HTML metadata is data about the HTML document. Metadata is not
>   displayed.
>
> Metadata typically define the document title, character set, styles,
>   links, scripts, and other meta information.

But I tested myself, and the images do work if the image exists in the path. Please check the image exists in the location you have in the `img` tag.

I am assuming you have uploaded the images along with the html file. If not please upload the images through filezilla to the correct location.

The best way to find what is the issue is to check the browser console. You may find an error saying no image found in `path/to/your/image` and that is where you have to put your image!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is malformed and does not have an opening `<body>` tag, which could be causing some issues.  I'd recommend using the [W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to validate your code.

Errors like this are easier to visually spot if you use some sort of code-formatting/"pretty-print" tool (I like [this one](http://htmlformatter.com/)). 
 Notepad++ probably has a plugin for this as well.